# Empty values are added as last Argument when reading parameters using sampler.getArguments().getArgumentsAsMap() - Jmeter JSR223 Preprocessor

Tags: jmeter

I m sending a httprequest nd using formdata as Content type.I added Values in Jmeter Parameter tab and read those parametrs in Preprocessor using sampler.getArguments().getArgumentsAsMap().But one empty key value pair is addded at the last in that map.
[image]

Code :
jsonPayload = JsonOutput.toJson(sampler.getArguments().getArgumentsAsMap())
log.info("Arguments as Map"+jsonPayload)

Result :
2022-12-23 12:40:49,347 INFO o.a.j.m.J.Encrypt Payload: Arguments as Map{"Name":"test1","ID1":"test2","tID2":"test3","ID3":"test4","":""}

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue using [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5) and a single simple [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler:

[image]

So it might be the case there is another HTTP Request sampler with another empty argument somewhere in the JSR223 PreProcessor's [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) or you're adding an empty argument somewhere else and it appears in the second iteration.